# Iterate on json structure with Poco

Tags: c++, json, dynamic, poco-libraries

I'm using Poco library for C++ code

Here is an example of the json tree I have to parse

```
{
    "name" : "actionToDo",
    "description" : "",
    "version" : "1",
    "parameters" : {
        "inputDirectory" : "string",
        "workingDir" : "string",
        "tempDir" : "string",
        "size" : "integer"
    }
}
```

The amount of data into "parameters" field can change.
I have to put all items into a map

Here my code today

```
std:: map<std::string, std::string> output;

Poco::JSON::Parser sparser;
Poco::Dynamic::Var result = sparser.parse(jsonStr);
Poco::JSON::Object::Ptr object = result.extract<Poco::JSON::Object::Ptr>();
Poco::DynamicStruct ds = *object;

Poco::Dynamic::Var collection(ds["parameters"]);

if (collection.isStruct())
{
     LOG("STRUCT"); //it's logged !!
}

for (Poco::Dynamic::VarIterator it = collection.begin(); it != collection.end(); ++it)
{
    LOG_F("item : %s", it->toString()); //never logged
    //here I would like to have something like
    //output[it->first()] = it->second();

}
```

And the output I got

> 14:13:00'900 :  : [Notice] : STRUCT
>
> 14:13:00'900 :  : [Critical] : Exception : Exception: Unable to load Run from file :
>   /opt/.../file.json Exception:
>   Unable to parse field 'parameters' or its children
>
> Invalid access: Not a struct.

The "Unable to parse field 'parameters' or its children" is generated by a catch below but the "Invalid access: Not a struct." comes from Poco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use for *collection* variable *DynamicStruct* instead of *Var*

```
Poco::DynamicStruct collection = ds["parameters"].extract<Poco::DynamicStruct>();

for (auto it = collection.begin(); it != collection.end(); ++it)
{
    LOG_F("item : %s", it->second.toString().c_str());
}
```